# Having multiple root app for login component

Tags: angular

I want a login page where people are navigated to by default with no layout. If they succeed login they will be redirected to the main application. What's the normal approach to this? Do you have multiple `.html` files and multiple root components or how do you normally implement this? I want to be able to inject services etc between the root. As an example, I have an ADAL service from the login root I need to be able to access the main app root. Also, the routing part, do you need multiple routers too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically, you need to implement route guards to control users to directly access your other route pages. You can follow [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) tutorial to guard your application.

Implementing the Angular's **Route Guards** the suggested approach you should follow for Angular Applications

Answer (score 0):

with help of router-outlet directive, you can configure the various component will be loaded with the help of URL. You can configure the router Config in Root Router Module.

```
const login_routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', canActivate: [LoginGuard], component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent }
];
```

When user access /login, which will call the loginGuard to validate whether user login. if not redirect to ADAL URL or else redirect to Home Page.

If you have lazy loaded module which needs to be loaded on demand. You can have the router Config

```
const login_routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', canActivate: [LoginGuard], component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/src/home.module#HomeModule' }
];
```

Comment: What code you have in the LoginGuard? And can you have multiplee guards? I allready have an ADAL guard from thre library I am using.

Answer (score 0):

For Reference:- [How to use angular 6 Route Auth Guards for all routes Root and Child Routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485433/how-to-use-angular-6-route-auth-guards-for-all-routes-root-and-child-routes/52515252#52515252)

```
1) 
ng generate guard auth   [ Create guard, the file name would be like auth.guard.ts ]

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
'@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
    private myRoute: Router){
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(this.auth.isLoggednIn()){
      return true;
    }else{
      this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
      return false;
    }
  }
}


2)  ng g c login  [Create login page ]
ng g c nav  [Create nav page ]
ng g c home  [Create home page ]
ng g c registration  [Create registration page ]


3)  App.module.ts file add below contents

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule,Router,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';

const myRoots: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' , canActivate: 
[AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      myRoots,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [AuthService,AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


4) Add link in nav.component.html

<p color="primary">
  <button  routerLink="/home">Home</button>
  <button  *ngIf="!auth.isLoggednIn()" routerLink="/register">Register</button>
  <button  *ngIf="!auth.isLoggednIn()" routerLink="/login">Login</button>
  <button  *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()" (click)="auth.logout()">Logout</button>
</p>


4.1)  Add in nav.component.ts file

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}


5) 
ng g service auth  [Create service page Add below code in authservice.ts]

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private myRoute: Router) { }
  sendToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("LoggedInUser", token)
  }
  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("LoggedInUser")
  }
  isLoggednIn() {
    return this.getToken() !== null;
  }
  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("LoggedInUser");
    this.myRoute.navigate(["Login"]);
  }
}


6) add content in login.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private myRoute: Router,
    private auth: AuthService) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.auth.sendToken(this.form.value.email)
      this.myRoute.navigate(["home"]);
    }
  }
}


6.1)  add in logincomponent.html page

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
<div>
<input  type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" />
</div>
<div>
<input  type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" />
</div>
<button type="submit" color="primary">Login</button>
</form>

7) Add below code in app.component.html

<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I got the guards working, the thing I am looking for is more how I have components with different roots. My login component as an example should not have sidebar etc.